# Not able to access internet from WSL after updating to WSL2

Tags: linux, ubuntu, proxy, windows-subsystem-for-linux

After I updated my WSL to 2, I am not able to access internet from WSL. I am using ubuntu 20.04 as linux distribution. I am trying to use commands like git push or wget  but they give the error such as "Could not resolve host: github.com". These commands worked when using WSL version 1. I am not using a proxy. Please help. TIA